# Boy abducted by aliens

Tags: story-identification, childrens-novel

I'm trying to remember the name of a book that I read in the 90's.  It was a YA novel about a nerdy kid who was abducted by aliens and ends up travelling with them for awhile.  There were a couple of sequels I believe, about how the aliens are going to destroy the earth unless the boy can prove there is some good here.

Answer (score 5):

If it wasn't for being across sequels this sounds rather like Heinlien's [*Have Spacesuit—Will Travel*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Have_Spacesuit,_Will_Travel).

Comment: Could still be _Have Space Suit_, since conversions of serials typically have an episodic feel to them.  It would be easy to misremember this as sequels instead of a single story.

Answer (score 5):

Ha! That sounds like [Bruce Coville's My Teacher is an Alien](http://www.brucecoville.com/books.asp?gid=3) and its subsequent sequels.

Comment: I would agree with this poster.